# Evening out margin space between video containers

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm having a little trouble trying to space out these video containers on a website. Here is the [example](http://8-playerpictures.com/portfolio/). I'm trying to get the grid gaps to be equal in margin. Right now the width of the horizontal margin between the containers is thicker than the vertical margins. It looks like the margin code I use is using a wrap around margin, which doubles the margin when placed next to each other. I've tried doing margin-right and margin-left and those haven't worked.

Would really appreciate your help!

Code is below:

```
#gallery { margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.video-container {
    width: 310px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    height: 310px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none; float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting line breaks (
) before the images inside your YouTube links that are adding vertical margin to your containers. For example:

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/vcdMZrmdwKU?iframe=true&amp;width=853&amp;height=480" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]">
    <br>
    <img src="http://8-playerpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Kinekt-Gear-Necklace.png" alt="Kinekt Design: Gear Necklace">
```

If you can find out where these are coming from and eliminate them, then you can control the vertical spacing of the containers using normal CSS.